# Highlighting active anchor link

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a menu in my sidebar that contains anchor links like so:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#anchor1">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#anchor2">Link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#anchor3">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now I need to highlight the active li in bold, so that when the user has the anchor link in view (for example by scrolling down the page or by having the link clicked), it is bold. How can I achieve this?

EDIT to clarify: my html to display the links is:

```
<div class="anchorlink id="anchor1">
<h2>Link 1</h2>
<p>Some text...</p>
</div>
<div class="anchorlink id="anchor2">
<h2>Link 2</h2>
<p>Some text...</p>
</div>
<div class="anchorlink id="anchor3">
<h2>Link 3</h2>
<p>Some text...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You will have to add a class to the active link. Otherwise I presume it will not be possible to find out which link is active. So I think there is no chance for this feature without the use of javascript

Answer (score 0):

Here I am using the [Intersection_Observer_API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

We need to tweak the margin to only have one link active when bits of the previous content is in the viewport

```js
let dir = 0
window.onscroll = function(e) {
  // print "false" if direction is down and "true" if up
  dir = this.oldScroll > this.scrollY ? 1 : -1;
  this.oldScroll = this.scrollY;
}

const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.content');
let callback = (entries, observer) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    const targetDiv = document.querySelector(`[href="#${entry.target.id}"]`);
    if (entry.isIntersecting) targetDiv.classList.add('active')
    const active = [...document.querySelectorAll('.active')];
    if (active.length > 1) active[dir === 1 ? 1 : 0].classList.remove("active")
  });
};

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback);
divs.forEach(div => observer.observe(div));
```

```css
.content {
  height: 700px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 50px
}
.active {
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul style="position: fixed">
  <li><a href="#anchor1">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#anchor2">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#anchor3">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div style="height:500px; overflow auto">
  <div class="content" id="anchor1">Anchor 1</div>
  <div class="content" id="anchor2">Anchor 2</div>
  <div class="content" id="anchor3">Anchor 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do I integrate this API? Sorry I have no javascript/jquery knowledge...

Comment: Just put them in a script tag after the html (before the end </body> tag and change "content" to whatever class YOU use in your divs. It would have been easier to answer if you had posted the HTML of the target content - now I just guessed

Comment: @flor48 there were some typos in my HTML. I removed some `div` strings

Comment: I used exactly your code but it does not add the active class...I integrated the script simply by adding it inside a <script></script> in the footer. Is there anything else I need to add?

Comment: Yes, your DIVS need the class I use or you need to change the class I use (`content`) to what YOU use. If you would only update the question with more HTML as I asked, I could help you better

Comment: Okay, I got it to work! It was adding the script inside the head and that did not work, but in the footer it works. However, I still have the issue of two anchor links being highlighted at the same time when both are in the viewport...my sidebar (where the anchor link menu is placed) is sticky if that makes any difference...

Comment: That was not trivial... See update

Comment: Okay, we are almost there! Two issues: I also have a fixed header, so I am adding .anchorlink{scroll-margin-top:80px}, but this results in issues with your code - the wrong link is highlighted when the fixed header is covering part of a section. Also, the links are highlighted IMMEDIATELY when scrolling up or down as soon as the section is visible, even if most of the viewport is still the other section. Can this be changed? Thank you!

Comment: Not by me. I think I went above and beyond.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an .active class applied to the current li, use `font-weight:bold`

```css
.active{
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#anchor1">Link 1</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="#anchor2">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#anchor3">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How do I apply an active class to the links on scroll? Wordpress(which I am using) does apply "current-menu-item" but that does not work on scroll, also it highlights EVERY anchor link since they are all on the same page.

Comment: I'm not sure of the best way to do it. In js, you make an event with `window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {});` and check your current position on page and compare to anchor position then use `element.classList.add("active")`.

Comment: I have no javascript/jquery knowledge, only HTML and CSS...

Answer (score 0):

Here the demo for has you want.

```js
$(".menu li a").click(function() {
    $('li a').not(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    var link1 = $('#home').offset().top;
    var link2 = $('#about').offset().top;
    var link3 = $('#contact').offset().top;
    

    
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      
        var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(winTop >= link1 && winTop < link2){
            $('.home').addClass("active");
        }
        else if(winTop >= link2 && winTop < link3){
            $('.about').addClass("active");
            $('.home').removeClass("active");
        } 
        else if(winTop >= link3){
            $('.about').removeClass("active");
            $('.contact').addClass("active");
        }else{
            $('a').removeClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
a.active{
  font-weight:bold;
}
html{
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
.menu{
  postion:relative;
}
.menu ul{
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
}
div{
  padding-top:100px;
}
#contact{
  padding-bottom:100px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home" class="home">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about" class="about">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact" class="contact">Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="home">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>

<div id="about">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>

<div id="contact">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Your script does not highlight the link matching the div in the viewport when scrolling- see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71998523/295783) for a comparison

Comment: change made please check :)